# Help Needed with Shaders

Tags: android, opengl-es2, google-cardboard

Ok, bear with me, I am a beginner with Google Cardboard programming.
What I have been doing is looking at the [TreasureHunter](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/treasure-hunt) sample app from Google's page and (with the help of documentation and other sources) have been trying to create a simple cube floating in space.
 I have also been trying to avoid making everything as bare bones as the sample, so I have been trying to object orient things such as lights and the meshes.

I am pretty sure that my matrices and methods are correct, but I think there could be something wrong with my shaders.

When I compile the app and install it, no errors are thrown, but I am given just my white screen (set with `glClearColor`) with the Cardboard binocular UI/view; no cube is rendered, tilting/looking around has no effect.

I am using the colors, verticies, and normals from the Treasure Hunter sample, so those should be correct.

Full source code (Java) is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmsq3b4pjocx832/java.zip?dl=0).

```
uniform mat4 u_Model; // model position in world space
uniform mat4 u_MVP;  // model in projection space
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix; // model in view space
uniform vec3 u_LightPos; // Light position in eye/camera space (projection space)

attribute vec4 a_Position; // vertex in local space
attribute vec4 a_Color; //Vertex colors
attribute vec3 a_Normal; //vertex normal

varying vec4 v_Color; // color
varying vec3 v_Grid;
varying vec3 v_Normal;
varying vec3 v_Position;

void main() {
   v_Grid = vec3(u_Model * a_Position);
   v_Normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));
   v_Position = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);
   vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position); //Vertex position in view space
   vec3 modelViewNormal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0)); //Normal in view space

   float distance = distance(u_LightPos, modelViewVertex);
   vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - modelViewVertex);
   float diffuse = max(dot(modelViewNormal, lightVector), 0.5);

   diffuse = diffuse * 1.0/(distance * distance);
   v_Color = a_Color * diffuse;
   gl_Position = u_MVP * a_Position;
}
```

My vertex shader:

My fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

Comment: Do they have any sample apps with a single triangle that you can start from? If not, that is very sad and someone needs to make one :p

Comment: @AlanWolfe, no they do not have a simple triangles sample. The have samples for VR videos and panorama photos, but nothing else for VR with OpenGL.

Comment: You should make every varying variable exist on both sides.

Comment: @Bálint, tried your suggestion, but sadly no effect :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was calculating my "u_MVP" (Model View Projection) matrix wrong. I used a vector instead of a matrix for the model position. That along with many other bugs. Now it's fixed.